# Prove by the method of Mathematical induction that $(1-0.3)^n \geq 1-0.3n$ for all $n$ in set of positive integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, formal-proofs

Here is what I have so far

**Basis**

For $n = 0   (1-0.3)^0 \geq 1-0.3(0)$ checks

For $n = 1   (1-0.3)^1 \geq 1-0.3(k$) checks

I.H. $(1-0.3)^k \geq 1-0.3(k)$ for all k in the set of positive integers (1)

We want to prove that $(1-0.3)^{k+1} \geq 1-0.3(k+1)$ (2)

To relate (1) to (2) we have to add $(1-0.3)^{k+1}$ to both sides of (1).

$(1-0.3)^k+(1-0.3)^{k+1} \geq 1-0.3(k) + (1-0.3)^{k+1}$.

Here is where I am stuck. I need help as to where to go from here.

Comment: Hint : Try binomial expansion of (1-0.3)^k+1 in equation 2 .

Comment: "To relate (1) to (2) we have to add (1−0.3)k+1 to both sides of (1)."  Why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you have to add $(1-0.3)^{k+1}$.

\begin{align}
(1-0.3)^{k+1} &= (1-0.3)(1-0.3)^k \\
&\geq (1-0.3) (1-0.3k) \\
&= 1-0.3-0.3k+0.3^2k \\
&=1-0.3(k+1)+0.3^2k \\
&\geq 1-0.3(k+1)
\end{align}

Comment: I was told that when solving this problem. You have to add (1-0.3)^k+1 to both sides of the induction hypotheses.

Comment: Did it occur to you to ask the person who told you that why?  Seeing as *we* didn't tell you any such thing, I don't see that we have to pay any attention to it.